# how i can check that parent is span or anchor in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how i can check in this code that the parent in loop is span or div.

```
$('a img, span img').each(function(n){
var c= $(this).parent();
console.warn(c)
});
```

i want to know if this possible to check that find the parent tag is span or anchor in html

how i can check in this code that the parent in loop is span or div.

```
$('a img, span img').each(function(n){
var c= $(this).parent();
console.warn(c)
});
```

i want to know if this possible to check that find the parent tag is span or anchor in html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$('a img, span img').each(function(n){
    var c = $(this).parent();
    if(c.is("span, a")) {
        //It's a span or an anchor!
    }
});
```

The `is` method returns `true` if any of the selected elements match the selector. In this case, the selected element is the parent, and the selector looks for either a `span` or an `a` element.

Alternatively, you could use `parent` with a selector and check the length of the resulting object:

```
$('a img, span img').each(function(n){
    if($(this).parent("span, a").length) {
        //It's a span or an anchor!
    }
});
```

The `is` method is [marginally faster](http://jsperf.com/jq-is-vs-parent) though (don't be misled by the apparently huge difference... the numbers are both quite low):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().is(/* selectors */);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).parents('div')<br/>
$(this).parents('span')<br/>
```

find parent div or span element

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get the tagname, as:

```
$('a img, span img').each(function(n){
  a = $(this).parent();
  console.log(a[0].nodeName)
});
```

Hope it helps